# C program to modify an existing record in file

Tags: c, file

Please advise me, I am a beginner at c. I have created a function to modify contacts in a file, the problem is that the record I modify gets inserted as a new record at the end of the file, but I need to replace the existing record with the new one. The code does get an input from user and checks its existence in the file to modify it with the new data, I used fseek() so the pointer navigates to the needed position, but nothing changed. Thank you in advance.

```
void modify(contact c[])
{
    
    FILE *f;
    int flag=0;
    int count_matches=0, match_cont_pos[100], choose;
    int k=0;

    char  name[50];

    FILE * file;
    file = fopen("info.txt", "ab+");
    char temp;


    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("\nEnter the name you want to search: ");
        scanf("%s",&name);

        for(int j = 0; name[j] != '\0'; j++)
            name[j] = tolower(name[j]);

        for(int i = 0; i < count ; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; c[i].last_name[j] != '\0'; j++)
                c[i].last_name[j] = tolower(c[i].last_name[j]);

            if(strcmp(c[i].last_name,name) == 0)
            {
                match_cont_pos[k]=i;
                k++;
            }

        }
        for(int d=0;d<k;d++)
            printf("match pos %d\n",match_cont_pos[d]);

        for(int d=0;d<k;d++){
            printf("\n%s\n%s\n%d %d %d\n%s\n%d\n%s\n\n", c[match_cont_pos[d]].last_name,c[match_cont_pos[d]].first_name,c[match_cont_pos[d]].DoB.day,c[match_cont_pos[d]].DoB.month,c[match_cont_pos[d]].DoB.year,c[match_cont_pos[d]].street_address,c[match_cont_pos[d]].phone_number,c[match_cont_pos[d]].email);
        }

        if(k>1){

            printf("Enter the number of the record you want to modify: ");
            scanf("%d",choose);

            printf("Enter last name: ");
            scanf("%s",&c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].last_name);
            printf("Enter first name: ");
            scanf("%s",&c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].first_name);
            printf("Enter phone number: ");
            scanf("%d",&c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].phone_number);
            printf("Enter email: ");
            scanf("%s",&c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].email);
            printf("Enter birth date: ");
            scanf("%d %d %d",&c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].DoB.day,&c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].DoB.month,&c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].DoB.year);
            printf("Enter the address: ");
            scanf("%c",&temp); // temp statement to clear buffer
            scanf("%[^\n]",&c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].street_address);
            rewind(file);
            
            fseek(file,-sizeof(c),SEEK_SET);
            
            fprintf(file,"%s,%s,%d-%d-%d,%s,%d,%s",c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].last_name,c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].first_name,c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].DoB.day,c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].DoB.month,c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].DoB.year,c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].street_address,c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].phone_number,c[match_cont_pos[choose-1]].email);
        }

    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: From the man page for `fopen`: "     ``a''   Open for writing.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.  Subsequent writes to the file will always end up at the then current end of file, irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.  Create the file if it does not exist."  You do not want mode 'a'.

Comment: First step: write on a piece of paper  several concrete examples of the content of your file. Second step, write on paper some  [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF) syntax describing your file content. Next step, read some book on C, or at least [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Then, read the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). The next day, type some code on your computer

Comment: And following up what William Pursell said, you *do* want "r+" or "rb+". Those will open a text or binary file (respectively) for reading and writing. The file must exist.

Comment: What do you think `fseek(file,-sizeof(c),SEEK_SET);` does? If you're working with a text file and do not have exact fixed size records then the only way you can reliably do this is to read the whole file and write the whole file with the replacement.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone,
@WilliamPursell, Ray yeah I changed the open to "r+" and it finally worked.
I have another question please, can you tell me how do I navigate to a certain line in the file, I man fseek() moves with letters, but is it possible to move with lines?

Comment: A file is a stream of bytes.  In order to move by lines, you need to build an index of the byte position of the start of each line. Or construct the file so that every line is a fixed size, so you can easily compute the byte position of the start of a line.

Comment: ok thank you very much, I will try that @WilliamPursell

Comment: Especially if the lines aren't guaranteed to be the same length, you may be better off copying the file to memory, modifying it there, and then just writing out the file from scratch, rather than tracking offsets and seeking back and forth. The seeking approach will generally be both more complicated and *much* slower.